# Cannot call function in $rootScope.$on AngularJS ui router

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, yeoman

I have a problem to use `$rootScope.$on` in AngularJS, I try to call alert, but unsuccess, nothing error in console, I generate this project use yeoman generator, I don't know why, this is my script, please correct my script.

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('siapApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$qProvider', 
    function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $qProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                    controller: 'MainCtrl'
                }
            }            
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
                    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
                }
            }            
        })

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
    }])

  .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toStateParams) {
        alert('success'); /*cannot call alert*/
      });

    }
  ]);
```

Please anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: try using `$transitions` instead. For _state change start_ that would be `$transitions.onStart({}, (transition) => { alert('success') });`. Don't forget to inject it

Comment: I have tried, but unsuccess too @AlekseySolovey

Answer (score 0):

This should work in any case. The only thing I can suspect is you don't have `ui-view` directive on your `index.html` page.

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Comment: still unsuccess